# accessing httpclient service from within another service in .net 5

Tags: .net-core, service, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

I am adding a httpclient as a service (within *ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)*) as follows:

```
 services.AddHttpClient<RequestsClient>(c =>
            {
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory");
            })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                return new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                };
            });
```

the *RequestsClient* class is constructed as:

```
public RequestsClient (HttpClient client, IHttpContextAccessor hca, ILogger<RequestsClient > log, Configuration config)
```

to use the *RequestsClient* service in any class/component needing it i'm injecting it as:

```
[Inject]
protected RequestsClient requestsClient { get; set; }
```

all this works great.

I'm now in need of creating a second service, lets call it *"TimedService"*.
How can I use my *RequestsClient* service from within my second service, *TimedService*?

injecting it like i do with components won't work as the *RequestsClient* always is null.
is there a way to give *TimedService* service access to my *RequestsClient* service?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constructor injection in `TimedService`.

```
public class TimedService
{
    private RequestsClient _requestClient;
    
    public TimedService(RequestsClient client)
    {
         _requestClient = client;
    }
}
```

I would recommend to go into typed client version. It is a bit more clearer in separation of code wise. See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) how to do this.